# Is there a turnkey solution for navigation?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

There is such a navigation:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

By pressing different items (buttons) of the menus, it is supposed to switch (change) the internal content
(highlighted in red marker).
The URL should not change when changing content!

Question:
Are there any ready-made solutions (tools) in vue.js or nuxt.js for this kind of problem?
If not, then what is the most appropriate strategy for implementing this task?
Should I use v-if(v-show) for inner content after button pressed?

Comment: Sounds like a tab component. Consider Vuetify's [`v-tab`](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101).

Comment: Or consider putting the views into individual components, and then use a [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) to display the component specified by the button pressed.